# SyntaxError: name 'moneyArray' is used prior to global declaration

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make my discord bot (discord.py) give people a daily amount of money  and read out their balances. The problem is I'm relatively inexperienced with programming in general and the discord.py API. This is is the best I could come up with to implement this (I haven't added a daily timer yet). The problem is when I run this, I get the error in the title. After looking up similar errors on stack overflow, I tried to add a global definition at the beginning of the function but it still gave me the error. Can anyone see the problem? Help would be greatly appreciated!

```python
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global moneyArray
    moneyArray = []
    peopleArray = []
    peopleArray.append(message.author.name)
    print(peopleArray)
    for x in message.guild.members:
        moneyArray.append(money)
    peopleid = peopleArray.index(message.author.name)
    print(peopleArray)
    #blah blah some more code
    if message.content.startswith('ub!bal'):
        peopleid = peopleArray.index(message.author.name)
        await message.channel.send('You have {} points!'.format(moneyArray[peopleid]))
    if message.content.startswith('ub!daily'):
            global moneyArray
            moneyArray[peopleid] += 10
            print(moneyArray[peopleid])
            await message.channel.send('10 points added!')
```

If requested I can share my entire code

Comment: Including the entire traceback, or at least indicate which line causes it could help.
However, it seems you only could have to get rid of the second 'global' to make this code work.

Comment: You just need to declare it as a global variable once outside client.event and i suggest you change the way to storing your points as it may reset the points of a player if 2 players have the same name on discord

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the duplicate `global moneyArray` line at line 16.

Your code should look like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global moneyArray
    moneyArray = []
    peopleArray = []
    peopleArray.append(message.author.name)
    print(peopleArray)
    for x in message.guild.members:
        moneyArray.append(money)
    peopleid = peopleArray.index(message.author.name)
    print(peopleArray)
    #blah blah some more code
    if message.content.startswith('ub!bal'):
        peopleid = peopleArray.index(message.author.name)
        await message.channel.send('You have {} points!'.format(moneyArray[peopleid]))
    if message.content.startswith('ub!daily'):
            moneyArray[peopleid] += 10
            print(moneyArray[peopleid])
            await message.channel.send('10 points added!')
```